# How to create shadow root inside a shadow root

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

I know this is easy using polymer but I want to do this using JavaScript

Shadow root > Shadow root  > shadow root

Answer (score 1):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-shadow-multiple discusses multiple shadow roots.

```
<div id="example1">Light DOM</div>
<script>
  var container = document.querySelector('#example1');
  var root1 = container.createShadowRoot();
  var root2 = container.createShadowRoot();
  root1.innerHTML = '<div>Root 1 FTW</div>';
  root2.innerHTML = '<div>Root 2 FTW</div>';
</script>
```

Comment: But what about nested?

Comment: Host nodes can host multiple shadow roots. There isn't really a notion of "nesting". What are you trying to do and maybe I can help explain it. An example would help.

Comment: You would have to have shadow -> element -> shadow -> element -> shadow. IOW, a shadow can't host a shadow, but it can host an element with a shadow.

Comment: @ebidel: Scott Miles is close to the answer that I seek. Can a Shadow Root host another shadow root or should it be like this? <Shadow Host>      Shadow Root           <Shadow Host2>                Root 2           </Shadow Host2> </Shadow Host>                                            It has to be more like Shadow >  element > shadow > element and so on right? And not Shadow>Shadow>Shadow?

Comment: An element needs to host a shadow root. My example is better seen in http://jsbin.com/zixakotiwepa/1/edit. It shows Polymer uses multiple shadow roots when extending elements. If you examine the element in the devtools, you'll see polymer-cooler has 2 `#shadow-root`s. Both extendee and extender have their own shadow roots.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same principle used to build a single shadow root to build a nested shadow-root:

```
<div id="shadow-host">
</div>
<script>
    var shadow = document.querySelector('#shadow-host').attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadow.innerHTML = '<div id=shadow-content><p>Shadow Root</p><div id="nested-shadow-host"></div></div>';
    var nestedShadow = shadow.querySelector('#nested-shadow-host').attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    nestedShadow.innerHTML = '<div id="nested-shadow-content"><p>Nested Shadow Root</p></div>';
</script>
```

[image: Example Nested Shadow Root]